# Register application as installed

Tags: vb.net, installation

I'm creating a little custom setup for my application, and I'm writing it in VB.NET. I'm not using an installer creator (like InnoSetup or someting else) because I need to download application files from the cloud and, honestly, I don't like the layout of default installers.

My question is: how do I register an application so that it shows out in the **Control Panel**? I've tried to create a subkey in: *HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall{FA82A5DD-E444-430F-9D60-10D20F5A8E4B}*, but nothing appears. My code is this:

```
Dim Key As RegistryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{FA82A5DD-E444-430F-9D60-10D20F5A8E4B}")
Key.SetValue("AuthorizedCDFPrefix", "", RegistryValueKind.String)
Key.SetValue("Comments", "", RegistryValueKind.String)
Key.SetValue("Contact", "http://www.hssc.com/jump", RegistryValueKind.String)
Key.SetValue("DisplayName", "Jump 2015 Edition", RegistryValueKind.String)
Key.SetValue("DisplayVersion", "5.0.0.0", RegistryValueKind.String)
Key.SetValue("EstimatedSize", 10485760, RegistryValueKind.DWord)
Key.SetValue("HelpLink", "http://www.hssc.com/jump")
Key.SetValue("HelpTelephone", "", RegistryValueKind.String)
Key.SetValue("InstallDate", String.Format("{0:yyyyddMM}", Now.Date), RegistryValueKind.String)
Key.SetValue("InstallLocation", "", RegistryValueKind.String)
Key.SetValue("InstallSource", "", RegistryValueKind.String)
Key.SetValue("Language", 1044, RegistryValueKind.DWord)
Key.SetValue("ModifyPath", "MsiExec.exe /I{FA82A5DD-E444-430F-9D60-10D20F5A8E4B}", RegistryValueKind.String)
Key.SetValue("Publisher", "HSSC", RegistryValueKind.String)
Key.SetValue("Readme", "", RegistryValueKind.String)
Key.SetValue("Size", "", RegistryValueKind.String)
Key.SetValue("SystemComponent", 1, RegistryValueKind.DWord)
Key.SetValue("UninstallString", "MsiExec.exe /I{FA82A5DD-E444-430F-9D60-10D20F5A8E4B}")
Key.SetValue("URLInfoAbout", "http://www.hssc.com/jump", RegistryValueKind.String)
Key.SetValue("URLUpdateInfo", "", RegistryValueKind.String)
Key.SetValue("VersionMajor", 5, RegistryValueKind.DWord)
Key.SetValue("VersionMinor", 0, RegistryValueKind.DWord)
```

And I've tried this too:

```
Dim KeyApp As RegistryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\jump.exe")
KeyApp.SetValue("", Path.Combine(InstallLocation, "jump.exe"), RegistryValueKind.String)
KeyApp.SetValue("Path", InstallLocation, RegistryValueKind.String)
```

But none of them works. The application is downloaded into Program Folders but it is not displayed in CP. My app has Administrative Rights and I'm working in **WinForms, Visual Studio 2013**.

Thanks,

*FWhite*

**EDIT**
Trying to insert the DisplayIcon value as suggested the result is this, but still no entry in the Control Panel. Am I missing something?
[image]

Comment: This question is too broad.  There are too many possible answers and/or the answer(s) would be too lengthy and complex.

Comment: what exactly are your trying to add to control panel: your app, an updater or uninstaller.  Control Panel doesnt seem like the right spot for any of them.

Comment: @Plutonix: I'm trying to add my program entry to the list of installed programs. So, the user should see: Jump 2015 Edition and, when the user right-clicks on the program entry, it can select Uninistall. I've already built a program to uninstall the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## EDIT

You've marked your software as a System Component (`"SystemComponent" = dword:00000001"`), meaning that it should show up in "Add/Remove Windows Components". So, just set SystemComponent to 0 or simply delete it. That should do it. :)

---

You're missing the "DisplayIcon" value. If you need, this is an example from WinRar subkey:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\WinRar archiver]
"DisplayName"="WinRar 5.10 (64-bit)"
"DisplayVersion"="5.10.0"
"VersionMajor"=dword:00000005
"VersionMinor"=dword:0000000a
"UninstallString"="G:\\Program Files\\WinRAR\\uninstall.exe"
"DisplayIcon"="G:\\Program Files\\WinRAR\\WinRAR.exe"
"InstallLocation"="G:\\Program Files\\WinRAR\\"
"NoModify"=dword:00000001
"NoRepair"=dword:00000001
"Language"=dword:00000000
"Publisher"="win.rar GmbH"
```

Comment: Hi Andre, I don't think this is the problem. Many other installed programs have not this value and they appear in the Control Panel...

Comment: Maybe the problem would be the empty **InstallLocation** value? I'm going to try

Comment: @PWhite Well, I've tried adding a key without the "DisplayIcon" value and it didn't show up in the Control Panel, so I thought that would be the case. Have you tried adding it anyway?

Comment: Ah, now it's clear! Your screenshot helped me figure it out. Check out my edit.